# Formatting Currency to ALWAYS use USD regardless of users culture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization

This should be simple but I cannot find the answer anywhere.
On our asp.net MVC site, we show currency values and I need these currency values to Always be in USD regardless of the users culture settings.

If I use string.format("{0:C}",value) then it shows the value in what ever culture the use has set.
This is incorrect for us as $1000.00 is not the same thing as 1000.00 euro

I still need to use the language side of this, meaning if they are in France I want to use the French localization resource, so I don't want to completely disregard their culture settings, but how can I make sure the currency is always shown in USD?

Comment: You seem to be expecting the formatting to also do currency conversion for you - is that the case?

Comment: Nope I don't want any conversions. I always want it to be in USD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to specify CurrentCulture to be en-US and leave CurrentUICulture as is.

I usually do this in global.asax.cs in the Application_BeginRequest event

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
     new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", false);
```

It is possible to specify the culture in web.config file but that has one drawback - it takes into account the customized regional settings of the server (if the administrator changed the currency or date format on the server for the en-US culture, it would get picked up this way) - so you can't ever be sure that the application will behave exactly the same as when you created/tested it.

Comment: wont this also set all the text to be in English? I still want to be able to show the culture language of the user.

Comment: +0: having cultures set differently for whole program solves some issues but I think brings more problems. (If it works for your case - code is obviously simpler, but the approach is not common, so may surprise next developer) Formatted strings will look strange when contain date/numbers as formatting will use different cultures for values and resource strings. I would recommend passing `CultureInfo` explicitly when needed and possible, or at least change culture for small chunks of code (i.e. reading from DB/files) and reverting back.

Comment: @twaldron, if this answer works for you - awesome. Just want to reiterate my comment - this will impact all Date/Time/Number formatting, so be very careful i.e. en-US and fr-FR day/month order does not have to match.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov thanks for that recommendation, I will go through and see what else it may affect. I appreciate it.

Comment: Note that you can also modify the CultureInfo that you created so you can look at the user preference, initialize the appropriate culture (say fr-FR) and change the currency text on it.

Answer (score 8):

Explicitly pass culture to the Format call:

```
string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C}",value)
```

If you have to mix it with other languages - save result of formatting currency value and insert into other places as string.

Side note: using "en-US" (or any other hard-coded culture) will lead to potentially mismatched representation of negative values i.e. some cultures use -100, while other (100) for negative amounts.

Comment: Thanks I new it would be easy. I was maybe hoping there was a global solution but this will certainly work. thanks again!

Comment: @twaldron - You can always set the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` before formatting and set them back.